# How can I add a static route via a remote server?

Tags: windows, routing, ip-forwarding

I have a remote (i.e., 3 hops away) hosted Linux VM, with some LXCs.
Those LXCs have internal IPs 10.0.3.*
The VM has IP forwarding enabled.

From my Windows machine, I would like to ping the inner LXCs, so I tried:

```
ROUTE ADD 10.0.3.* MASK 255.255.255.* <ip-of-remote-linux-vm>
```

But this does not work: all ping packets are timed-out.

I suspect that the reason is that the gateway (i.e., the Linux VM) is not on the same subnet as my windows machine.

Is there a way to make this routing work?

Comment: Does traffic to this machine traverse the public internet?

Comment: Yes, it is a hosted machine in a remote data center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing RFC1918 subnets over the public internet is unreliable at best, and is frequently impossible due to public internet routers being configured with ACLs that drop RFC1918 subnets (and others that shouldn't be on the public internet).

You'll need to build up some sort of VPN tunnel for this traffic. I'd recommend IPSec.